# Adding wrinkles to a game character

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, sculpting, cloth-simulation

I am trying to make a swat character for a game I am making.  I have shrink wrapped clothes on the character, but there is no wrinkles in the clothes to make it look realistic.  I want to keep the quads and tris low, but I also want good detail.  Also, when I export this player to Unity, do I join everything and export as one fbx? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you want to keep your clothes lowpoly but with details like wrinkles you should duplicate it, sculpt with dyntopo activated, then bake the normals

Comment: as for the unity part. Fbx - contrary to obj - does support multi object meshes, so you probably dont have to join but just export as fbx.

Comment: Thank you, when I bake the normals, does it include light data in the scene? Do I delete all lights?

Comment: Also, I have separate parts in the pants such as the belt loops and the belt.  Lets say I select all the parts of the pants and export to unity as FBX, will the parts be a child of the parent object? And will that work in animations such as walking.  If not, do I just apply a shrinkwrap with the verticies on the back of the loops with the pants as target and controll-j them?